# How to edit the html code of a custom footer module template override

Tags: module, template-override, joomla-3.5

i'm trying to create a modification of the footer Joomla copyright default module. I'm creating a template languge override, but this does't work very suitably,

i would like to know how to edit the text displayed in the footer

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your screenshot makes no sense, that's not the right place to override a module.

The Joomla footer module (`modules\mod_footer`) is a simple module that basically outputs some lines of text, and if you want to modify the output, the simplest solution is to add a `Custom` module from your module manager:

[image: Custom module]

Publish the module to the same position as your footer module, and unpublish the current one.

### Alternative

If you prefer to use the `mod_footer` module, you can override the output by copying the file `ROOT\modules\mod_footer\tmpl\default.php` to `ROOT\templates\YOURTEMPLATE\html\mod_footer\default.php`. Edit the file to suit your needs.

Comment: Hi johanpw! i just have published some screenshots more, your solution works well, i also had reached this approach. I think that also it is possible to solve this via mod_footer and language overrides for a specific template